# Mysql: How to SELECT only where column (accepted) is = 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code, it displays correctly except when I want to limit it only to filter 'accepted' from the friends table is = '1'… As of now its displaying where all

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, COUNT(friends.accepted) AS friends 
FROM users
  LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Do you mean the value of accepted = 1, or do you mean the number of accepted is 1?

Comment: the number of accepted is 1, the column is set to enum(0,1) @jarlh

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get only people with one accepted friend, use [`HAVING`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) (to keep it simple, `HAVING` is the equivalent of `WHERE` for filtering on aggregation results):

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, COUNT(*) AS friends 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
GROUP BY users.username
HAVING COUNT(friends.accepted) = 1
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20
```

If you want to count the friends where accepted = 1, a simple `WHERE` should work:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, COUNT(*) AS friends 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
WHERE friends.accepted = 1
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20
```

Or, if you want to also list people with no friend where accepted = 1:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, 
    SUM(CASE friends.accepted = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS friends 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: For some reason this is retrieving the table with friends = 1, instead of retrieving how many rows have accepted = 1

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't get the question. I edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: This leads me to ask you to better define your questions in the future, to avoid several possible interpretations.

Comment: Yes, I basically want to display who has the most friends, but only friend requests that have been accepted instead of all, this code is retrieving some numbers for the friends instead of the actual amount of friends @x.l.ant

Comment: Then the third query should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use having cluase to check the condition where count of accepted is 1 or not

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, COUNT(friends.accepted) AS friends 
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
  GROUP BY users.username
having count(friends.accepted)=1
  ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(columnname)` counts all records where columnname is not null. So it is not `COUNT(friends.accepted)` you want to use, because both 0 and 1 are not null, so you count all friends whether accepted or not.

Use SUM instead to count all accepted=1. In case a user has no friends at all you would get NULL, however. Use COALESCE for this case to make the NULL a zero, if this bothers you.

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  users.username, 
  users.avatar, 
  COALESCE(SUM(friends.accepted),0) AS friends 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON users.username IN (friends.user1, friends.user2)
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20;
```

(In your simple query where you are *only* interested in accepted friends, you could of course simply add `AND accepted = 1` to your ON clause, so as to get only accepted friends and count them with `COUNT`.)

Another way would be to count in a sub-query:

```
SELECT id, username, avatar, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from friends 
    where users.username in (friends.user1, friends.user2)
    and friends.accepted = 1
  ) as friends
FROM users
ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Sorry for the way I asked, I didn't know how to exactly ask, the code I was looking for is

Comment: SELECT users.id, users.username, users.avatar, COUNT(*) AS friends 
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.user1=users.username || friends.user2=users.username
    WHERE friends.accepted = '1'
    GROUP BY users.username
    ORDER BY friends DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: This gets you all accepted friends. You can turn your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN however, because your WHERE clause makes it an inner join implicitely anyhow. So this is what you wanted? A simple WHERE clause? :-) For code you can use the quote sign that looks like a tiny backslash (and a star at the beginning and end of a word or sentence make something *italic* und two stars **bold**).

Comment: thank you! testing
` code `
i just noticed it in the help box, didn't know it was referring to that, **thank!**